# Cannot Remote Login to Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a windows server 2003, and it is switched on all the time and remote connection enabled ( or so I thought). But the problem is that when I try to remote into it, when I click on the "connect" at the remote desktop dialog box, I am not logged in. In fact, that dialog box just refuse to go away, it acts as if I haven't click on the connect button.

Is there anywhere I can check to know what is the problem? In order word, I would love to know if there is a log file detailing every single successful/ unsuccessful remote connection made to connect to the server.

Answer (score 1):

are you try to connect locally from the internet remotely?
Have you opened the firewall ports?
If trying to connect remotely have you forwarded the correct ports to the server?
Have you ensured that Remote desktop is enabled on the server

try this from a command prompt window and see if it works telnet serverip 3389

Comment: I am aware that all these are possibilities. But my question is how to check? Is there an error log file somewhere?

Comment: There wont be an error in your server log file if you are not even able to make the connection, only if there is an authentication error.
You may have errors in your windows log from the PC you are trying to connect from
also the command I gave you 

telnet serverip 3389

will help you troubleshoot the connectivity

Answer (score 0):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784136(WS.10).aspx

Refer above link that will help you to enable/disable remote connection logging.